# Can Android Presentation handle touch events?

Tags: android

I know that Android [Presentations](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Presentation.html) can have their own layouts which means I can create UI components like buttons etc. However, does anyone know if it is possible for Presentations to handle touch events?

I have tried adding a button on the Presentation layout and registering a button onClickListener but it seems to not be working. Is there another way?

Here is my code:

In my Presentation class

```
mHelloToast = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_presentation_hello_toast);
    mHelloToast.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getContext(), "hello presentation", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT );
            toast.show();
        }
    });
```

Edit: bump

Comment: What do you mean by presentation? I have literally never heard that term being used anywhere. Just looking at your code it should be fine, so we need more information to help you. In general: Of course any UI component can handle touch events, how else is the user supposed to interact with anything?

Comment: @XaverKapeller I have added a link to the api for presentations in my edit but a presentation is pretty much displaying a layout on an external display.

Comment: Oh ok, I don't really know much about that, however it seems likely since the samples on the page you link to are displaying a Dialog which is obviously a UI element that requires direct user interaction.

Answer (score 0):

[Doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Presentation.html) says:

> A presentation is a special kind of dialog whose purpose is to present content on a secondary display. A Presentation is associated with the target Display at creation time and configures its context and resource configuration according to the display's metrics.

So I think `Android Presention` can handle touche event as `Dialog`.Here I will show you how `Dialog` handles touch event.

### Step 1

Create your custom layout `res/layout/dialog_signin.xml`.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_presentation_hello_toast"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

### Step 2

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
// Get the layout inflater
LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
// Get the view which you want to receive touch event
//// Pass null as the parent view because its going in the dialog layout
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_signin, null);
Button bt = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn_presentation_hello_toast);
// set click or touch listener
bt.setOnClickListener(....);

// set dialog's contents
builder.setView(rootView);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I don't think this is what I am looking for. My goal is to be able to put UI on my Presentation and display it on an external device then interact with the external display by doing touch interaction with the external display.